# CONCAT() function not recognised when running code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use w3schools to practise SQL. I want to practise using SQL Server so I followed the 'try it yourself' link on the following page where the code shows `SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Customers;`

It's my understanding this reads the code as SQL Server i.e `SELECT TOP 3` is syntax for SQL Server.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

What I don't understand is why the below code doesn't work on the screen 'try it yourself' takes me to:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top&ss=-1

Running this returns

> Error in SQL: Undefined function 'CONCAT' in expression.

It sounds like it doesn't understand what `CONCAT()` means. This is a SQL Server function though isn't it? Why wouldn't it recognise it?

`SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(CategoryName,' ',LEN(CategoryName)) FROM Categories`

Comment: What is your sql server version?

Comment: I guess CONCAT() function is not supported, or W3School might be using an older version of SQL Server. CONCAT() function is introduced in SQL Server 2012  and can be used in versions released after SQL Server 2012

Comment: Looks like MS Access as & operator is working. For example  SELECT  'a'&'b' is working.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 (CategoryName + ' '  + LEN(CategoryName)) AS CategoryName FROM Categories` is working?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 (CategoryName & ' ' & LEN(CategoryName)) as ss FROM Categories` this statement is working on given link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top&ss=-1

Comment: The "SQL Tryit editor" doesn't use sql server, it uses webSQL.

Comment: You are basically asking us why some website that has a sql tool on it isn't supporting a sql function. That would be a question for the people who wrote and maintain that site. Not the people on an online forum unrelated to that website.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top&ss=-1 is using Microsoft Access/Jet (not SQL Server). If you try `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` it says:

> This is a read-only, MS Access Database, and you are not allowed to do
>   that.

Try using: http://sqlfiddle.com or https://dbfiddle.uk, where you can select the desired database engine.